# swift 3 - ViewController not deselecting selected rows in a UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I have a tableview where the user is able to select multiple rows (these rows are distinguished by a checkbox in the row).  For some reason, however, I can't implement the functionality to deselect any selected row.  Can somebody tell me what I'm missing?

**SomeViewController.m**

```
@objc class SomeViewController: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var deviceArray:[Device] = []

    // [perform a fetch]
    // [insert fetch results into deviceArray to be displayed in the tableview]

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customcell", for:
        indexPath)

        // Set up the cell
        let device = self.deviceArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = device.name

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath).accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.checkmark
        NSLog("Selected Row")
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        self.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath).accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
        NSLog("Deselected Row")
    }
}
```

**More info:**
Looking at the debug logs inserted, I can share the following observations:

1. When selecting an unselected row, the console prints "Selected Row"
2. If I click the same row from observation #1, the console prints "Selected Row" only
3. If I click on any other row, the console prints "Deselected Row" and then "Selected Row"
4. If I click on the same row as observation #3, the console prints "Selected Row" only.

So, it looks like everytime I click on a different row, tableView: didDeselectRowAt: gets called; however, checkmarks in the clicked row do not go away.

**More Info 2:**

So I'm new to storyboards and didn't set the "allowsMultipleSelection" property.  Going into the Attributes Inspector, this is what my settings look like:

[image]

Now, when pressing the same row in the tableView, my console confirms that the app is alternating between tableView:didSelectRowAt: and tableView:didDeselectRowAt:, however, the checkmark doesn't disappear; once the user selects a row, the checkmark remains selected even when tableView:didDeselectRowAt: is called.  What else am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off make sure your datasource AND delegate outlets are set if you are setting them from storyboard.

[image]

Another thing is you need to set `allowsMultipleSelection` property to true to get the `didSelect`, `didDeselect` methods to get called in the behavior you want. Otherwise it will always call `didSelect` for the cell you tapped on and `didDeselect` for the most previously selected cell.

The other thing to note is that you are referencing `self.tableView` when setting your `cell.accessoryType` property. This may be different instance of the tableView being passed into the delegate method. I recommend a `guard let` statment to ensure the code setting the accessory type only applies if the `tableView` being passed into the function. Here is code I used to get it to work.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //Notice I use tableView being passed into func instead of self.tableView
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else {
        return
    }
    cell.accessoryType = .checkmark

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else {
        return
    }
    cell.accessoryType = .none
}
```

Comment: I tested the rest of your code from method1 and it works for me so the only thing I can think of is your method's aren't being called. Which would happen if you didn't set the delegate.

Comment: Thanks for testing my code, NSGangster.  Checking my datasource and delegate outlets, I can confirm that they are set from the storyboard.  My "Referencing Outlet", however, is not (as depicted in your screenshot) but I'm not able to set it to the tableview (I can only set it to the view for some strange reason).  Also, I think my UITable delegate methods are being hit(I can confirm via the debugger), it's just that the selected rows are having their checkboxes removed when I select them.  Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you not use the tableView at all in your viewController class outside of datasource and delegate methods? Do you have more code elsewhere where another tableView is being created? Also it sounds like you checkmarks enabled on cells by default?

Comment: Just updated the question with more observations.  No, the checkmarks are not enabled on cells by default.  This tableview is the only tableView in this view controller.

Comment: I feel like "allowsMultipleSelection" property is not being set to true. But I am assuming you set this via storyboard?

Comment: No actually, I did not... didn't know about that property.

Comment: After setting the allowsMultipleSelectionProperty, the log confirms that pressing the same button alternates between calling tableView:didSelectRowAt: and tableView:didDeselectRowAt:, however, the checkmark doesn't go way when tableView:didDeselectRowAt is called.  I'm new to storyboards so let's not assume I'm doing anything correctly!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136981/discussion-between-nsgangster-and-vee).

Answer (score 0):

If you want user to be able to select multiple cells, you need to set `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true` in the `viewDidLoad` method or set multiple selection in the attributes inspector.

Comment: Thank Andrey - I did end up setting the allowMultipleSelection property in the attributes inspector.  Now, the log confirms that pressing the same button alternates between calling tableView:didSelectRowAt: and tableView:didDeselectRowAt:, however, the checkmark doesn't go way when tableView:didDeselectRowAt is called.  Something else I'm missing?